# First impressions on iOS SE app, as relates to Code Review

Tags: discussion

I have taken a number of screen captures of different interactions one would have with SE, specifically on the Code Review site. Here are some of my early observations.

*Please note: Throughout this trial the iPad has been held horizontally, mostly. The layout is not quite as good with vertical orientation.*

## A question:

[image: Question]

## An answer to said question, with comments:

[image: Answer]

## Profile

*Note: I had the quick navigation menu open, it's on the left. Can be reduced easily.*

[image: Profile]

## Feed

This shows hot network questions in a horizontally scrollable interface. It also seems to display recent questions on your "hottest" networks.

[image: Feed]

## Search filters

When you click on the "Active" word in the left dashboard, it gives you a number of filtering options:

[image: Search filters]

## "Tags" view

[image: tags]

## "User" view

[image: UserProfile]

---

## ***Flipping to vertical view!***

## Test Q&A view, showing editing and preview panes

<strike>The code block seems to not be up to par yet, which is a big deal for CR.</strike>

[image: Code Block]

---

## ***Flipping back to horizontal view!***

## Large code blocks

Scrollbars for long sections of code seem to be gone on iOS app:

[image: good_things]

And that seems to be good on both questions and answers.

[image: good_things2]

Comment: Preview doesn't support MathJax? Lame sauce.

Comment: Appears to be the case. Wouldn't surprise me if that was coming along pretty soon though. Nevertheless, it works pretty good otherwise.

Comment: I suspect your non-working code block was because it's located just below a list. You need to put an empty html comment to make the code block *not part of* the list, or add a bunch of more spaces (6 IIRC) to make the code block part of the last list bullet - in which case the code block gets indented in line with the bullet/numbered list items. This behavior is normal stuff, does it not work in IE? ;)

Comment: Fixed and updated post.